# JQuery Appear .addClass and CSS Transition?

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I want to understand how a particular JQuery effect was implemented. On [this design company's website](http://aetherthemes.com/visia-joomla/), pictures of tablets and people "pop up" when you reach the "About Us" and "The Team" sections. How can I recreate the effect?

I tried to copy-paste the jquery code from the page but couldn't get it to work work. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

```
jQuery('.animated').appear();
jQuery(document.body).on('appear', '.slide', function () {
    jQuery(this).each(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('ae-animation-slide')
    });
});
```

Here is the full code in
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RcvWM/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it seems no DOM is not ready. Use `$(document).ready()` to tell JQuery to wait until the page is finished loading to run JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //put codes in here.
})
```

I tried your JSFiddle but it seems not showing the image, if you update JSFiddle I can look into again.

Try this updated Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RcvWM/3/

I added webkit css and loaded the jQuery Appear plugin. Make sure you have that included.

```
.ae-animation-slide {
    -webkit-animation-name: ae-animation-slide;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RcvWM/2/ update! im pretty bad at jquery! Anyway i have update the image if possible i want that the jquery put the "ae-animation-slide" into the img class so when someone visit the page become visible in the browser view port with a nice CSS3 transition effect.

Comment: yet in JSFiddle work perfect i gonna try later to put into my website! Ty a lot!